# Export data to CSV files using CURL in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, export-to-csv, google-cloud-sql

I get an error when I run CURL in the terminal. The error is like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Here my CURL code :

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"exportContext":
                {"fileType": "CSV",
                 "uri": "gs://project-initial-db/test_gutil.csv",
                 "databases": ["my_db"] },
                 "csvExportOptions": 
                     {"selectQuery":"SELECT * FROM `trans_channel` INTO OUTFILE "test_gutil.csv" CHARACTER SET "utf8mb4" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "\"" ESCAPED BY "\\" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";"}}' \
   -X POST \
   https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-11/instances/project-db/export
```

Does anybody know about this error?

I seek out about export to CSV using CURL on Google Cloud SQL, but I just get a little bit of information.

FYI, I have set the environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) and the authentication is successful.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Just for your sake, you should replace your personal data, such as project name and instance name, for placeholders, so that you do not share that with everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a little something within thew field "cvsExportOptions", it should look like this:

```
"csvExportOptions": 
                 {"selectQuery":"[YOUR_QUERY]"}
```

You may have more detailed information [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export), where you can also check if the curl is correct using the Try the API utility on the right of the page.

**EDIT**

Copying the api call from the Try this API utility I used for testing exactly as it was worked for me. Give this a try replacing the placeholders with your data

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{
  "exportContext": {
    "fileType": "CSV",
    "uri": "gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/[YOUR_PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE]",
    "databases": [
      "[YOUR_DATABASE]"
    ],
    "csvExportOptions": {
      "selectQuery": "[YOUR_QUERY]"
    }
  }
}' \
   -X POST \
   https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]/instances/[YOUR_INSTANCE]/export
```

Comment: I have added "selectQuery", but the results are still the same.

Comment: Alright, I think I made it work. I believe that, within your code, that is the example code in the link in the answer, there must be some invisible character that cannot be properly parsed. What I did was test my api call in the Try the API utility, and after seeing that it worked, I copied it and paste it as is within the parameter "--data". I will edit my answer with the exact code that worked for me (except for the personal data).